# MySQL Dump using query

Tags: mysql

I want to dump my DB with a click on a button in my C#.Net App.
I thought about using

```
Process.Start(@"mysqldump", @"-u root -p mydb > dump.sql");
```

but this command opens a command prompt asking for the MySQL user password.

how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this command :

```
mysql -u root -p mydb > dump.sql
```

Try using this, passing the password in the command, so `mysqldump` doesn't ask for it :

```
mysqldump -u root --password=YOUR_PASSWORD mydb > dump.sql
```